# Python Tkinter Sibling windows interacting

Tags: python, tkinter

Well I am 1000 lines into my first Python / Tkinter Project. Time for some pointers to keep me on the path.
So I want to have the Display Layout button initially disabled (greyed out). After a file is loaded the Display Layout is active.

```
def ReadFile()
    #Something Magical Happens
    Layoutbutton.config(state='active')

def DisplayLayout()
    #Draw Great gobs of stuff

def main()
    global Layoutbutton
    #setup root window yada yada yada
    Layoutbutton=Button(root,text="Layout",command=DisplayLayout,underline=0)
    Layoutbutton.place(relx=.5,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
    root.bind("l",DisplayLayout)
    root.bind('L',DisplayLayout)
    Layoutbutton.config(state='disabled')

    BrowesButton=Button(root,text="File",command=ReadFile,underline=0)
    BrowesButton.place(relx=.75,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
    root.bind("F",ReadFile)
    root.bind('f',ReadFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root=Tk()
    main()
```

This all works as expected. The DisplayLayout button is geryed out until a file is read.

I am questioning the use of global LayoutButton. I have a lot of this type of thing going on.
How do (for lack of a better term) sibling windows communicate with each other without too many globals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around the use of globals by objectifying your code. For example a different implementation of your example may be:

```
def read_file():
    #magic happens    

class MyFrame(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.layout_button = Button(self.parent,text="Layout",
                             command=self.display_layout,underline=0)
        self.layout_button.place(relx=.5,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
        self.parent.bind("l",self.display_layout)
        self.parent.bind('L',self.display_layout)
        self.layout_button.config(state='disabled')
        self.browes_button=Button(self.parent,text="File",
                                  command=self._call_read_file,underline=0)
        self.browes_button.place(relx=.75,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
        self.parent.bind("F",self._call_read_file)
        self.parent.bind('f',self._call_read_file)

    def display_layout(self):
        #populate frame etc. 

    def _call_read_file(self):
        read_file()
        self.layout_button.config(state='active')

def main(root):
    frame = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
```

This may be personal preference, but I find GUI designing much more intuitive like this, and it is easier to track down unwanted behaviours compared to code that makes heavy use of globals. By this method every frame keeps a reference to its parent frame, essentially giving all the frames access to each other should they need to make updates. A complete and rather stupid example might be:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyOtherFrame(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.enable_button = tk.Button(self.root,text="enable",command=self.enable)
        self.enable_button.pack()
        self.disable_button = tk.Button(self.root,text="disable",command=self.disable)
        self.disable_button.pack()
        self.child_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.child_frame.pack()
        self.child_frame_obj = MyFrame(self.child_frame)

    def enable(self):
        self.child_frame_obj.button.config(state="active")

    def disable(self):
        self.child_frame_obj.button.config(state="disabled")

class MyFrame(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root,text="useless button")
        self.button.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    x = MyOtherFrame(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the function `ReadFile` to accept a parameter:

```
def ReadFile(LayoutButton):
    #Something Magical Happens
    LayoutButton.config(state='active')
```

Define a function inside `main` that call the `ReadFile` with `LayoutButton`. Replace occurence of `ReadFile` with the new fucntion.

```
def main():
    #global Layoutbutton   # No need to declare LayoutButton as global.

    def wrapper(event=None):          # <-------
        return ReadFile(Layoutbutton) # <-------

    #setup root window yada yada yada
    Layoutbutton=Button(root,text="Layout",command=wrapper,underline=0) # <--
    Layoutbutton.place(relx=.5,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
    root.bind("l",DisplayLayout)
    root.bind('L',DisplayLayout)
    Layoutbutton.config(state='disabled')

    BrowesButton=Button(root,text="File",command=wrapper,underline=0)   # <--
    BrowesButton.place(relx=.75,rely=.85,anchor=CENTER)
    root.bind("F", wrapper) # <-------
    root.bind('f', wrapper) # <-------
```

Alternatively you can use `lambda` instead of the function:

```
wrapper = lambda event=None: ReadFile(Layoutbutton).
```

Or structure the program using class.